# Something went wrong, now I've only got a WSOD

Tags: joomla-3.4

Basically, my problem is as it says above. I don't know what happened but I've only got a WSOD now and I can't find the error. How do I fix this?

To recap what I was did today:

First, I upgraded from 3.4.5 to 3.4.7.

Then, I installed a new extension called "Responsivizer".

At some point, I'm not sure when, I got this error:

```
Incorrect key file for table '/mysql-tmp/#sql_231ee_1.MYI'; try to repair it SQL=SHOW FULL COLUMNS FROM `y2sk4_postinstall_messages`  An error has occurred.
```

I kept working on the website because it didn't seem to affect anything and I can still work on it. Then, I added new menu modules for the mobile menu to be placed on the Responsivizer menu positions. When I tried to reload the page, all I got was a white screen and nothing. I thought it was just me and my slow connection but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Please, help. How do I fix this?

This is the website, by the way: http://www.glenatgrandview.com/.

Answer (score 1):

So, I rolled back everything and... I stopped at the point when I uninstalled Responsiviser because it was then that the frontend was restored.